# Pycharm: How to get the output console once closed?

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm Community 2019.3

I have accidentally closed the output window, and now I can only see it if i "Run", but can't seem to find it on "Debug".

This is what I do have on debug

[image: no run output]

How to get my output window back on debug?

This is the window I get if I "run"

[image]

---

This is my tools menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the `Debug` window, you should have two tabs: <kbd>Debugger</kbd> and <kbd>Console</kbd>:
  [image: An image showing the debug toolbar with the "Debugger" and "Console" tabs highlighted]
- From your images I can see that by *output window* you mean the console. So if indeed you have that missing, right click the <kbd>Debugger</kbd> tab -> `Layout` -> and select <kbd>Console</kbd>:
  [image: An image showing the context menu of right-clicking on the "Debugger" tab, and then opening the "Layout" sub-menu]
  And Voila:
  [image: An image showing the debug toolbar with both tabs appearing after clicking on "Console" in the previous step]

---

More information and ways in the official [JetBrains help center](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debug-tool-window.html#hide_restore).

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar of the debug console, click the button Python console.
Then, From the main menu, choose Tools | Open Debug Command Line.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have added a picture of my tools menu.